# How can I use aws to secure a domain with https for a non aws origin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I did a search in the aws docs and couldn't find anything that could help me to setup a cloudfront distribution for a non aws origin server to secure my domain with https. I'm using route 53 to manage my dns for the domain, I'd like to setup https for the domain but it is not hosted with aws. How can I use aws to create a secure domain with https?

Update: I've created the cloudfront distribution and set the alternative cnames to the domain (example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)). In Route 53 I updated the A record for the domain - example.com - to be an alias and pointed it to the cloudfront distribution, but when I try to access the site I get page not working error. The domain does now have he secure padlock, but I can't access the site. Here is the error that I get when I access the site:

[image]

Comment: Just use Certificate Manager on AWS to set it up.  You'll just verify ownership via adding a CNAME record.

Comment: @bkunzi01 I've already done that. I have generated the certificate with a wild card so that it covers subdomains. I created a cloudfront distribution and used the origin, which is not hosted with aws. but when I access the site I get a message that It cannot connect securely.

Comment: @Abdi you need to edit your question to include all those details about what you have setup and what isn't working. Are you sure you have your domain pointing to Cloudfront?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use a CloudFront distribution in front of your non AWS endpoint. This endpoint would be configured as a custom origin endpoint.

You would need to generate or upload a certificate to [ACM](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/) to attach to the resource. This must be done before you can use the distribution on your own domain, if you don't have it when you create the distribution you will need to edit it later.

The AWS documentation includes documentation for [Creating a Distribution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-creating-console.html). If you follow this and reference your endpoint as the custom origin you will be able to create the host.

You will need to ensure you configure the Origins `Origin Protocol Policy` option to be `HTTP Only` if your host does not have a HTTPS certificate.

Be aware that as the CloudFront distribution communicates with your endpoint over the internet, any traffic between CloudFront and your endpoint will still not be encrypted.

Comment: Right. I've created the distribution, do I need to do anything in Route 53? How can I use https for the domain after creating the cloudfront distribution?

Comment: If your domain is in Route 53, update the record to be an Alias record and reference your CloudFront distribution CNAME. This will then have your domain resolve to CloudFront, as long as you added your domain as an alternative name to CloudFront it should work

Comment: So, I've created the cloudfront distribution and set the alternative cnames to the domain (example.com and www.example.com). In Route 53 I update the A record for the domain - example.com - to be a alias and pointed it to the cloudfront distribution, but when I try to access the site I get page not working error. The domain does now have he secure padlock, but I can't access the site. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of error exactly are you getting, is there any HTML returned?

Comment: I've updated the OP, I put a screenshot of the error in the main question.

Comment: Do you get anymore details from the browser? You sometimes see this when caught in a redirect loop.

If you run ` curl -iv $YOUR_DOMAIN` does it return any signs of a redirect?

Comment: Yes, it's in a redirect loop: "This page isn’t working ----.com redirected you too many times.Try clearing your cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Comment: Presume this is also the same in incognito? Have you enabled anything on CloudFront for redirecting? Does the app do any redirecting? Can you see anything in the app logs?

Comment: Yes, it's the same in incognito mode. I haven't enabled anything in cloudfront for redirecting. I used the defaults for most settings.

Comment: If you run `curl -iv $YOURDOMAIN` does it try to redirect to itself? Are you able to see the redirect loops in your web server access logs?